# Mysql max_connection limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have to increase the max_connection limit of mysql increase to 1000.

By edit the /etc/my.cnf also another way by SET GLOBAL max_connection=1000.

Its update the varibale size of max_connections=1000 but when i test my site with 100,200...400 concurrent users respectively but the max_connection cant go high more than 150.

Please help me out on this query.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-start your server. For any configuration to take effect, it requires reloading.
2. It is not for 'concurrent users' it means, how many connections you can open.
3. Bandwidth plays an important role. What is the response header that you get? Are you sure it is MySQL only? 1000 concurrent users = 1000 concurrent database queries. What about spooling mechanism?
4. What you're trying to do is `max_user_connections` and NOT `max_connections` . I assumed it when you wrote " *i test my site with 100,200...400 concurrent users respectively but the max_connection cant go high more than 150.* "

Comment: When i am do the load-test. Set the parameter max_connection=1000 and max_users_connection=10000. At that time CPU utilization is ok but DB connection reach to the level of 150 it go steady condition even it can't go high or down. The issue is that why it can't go high more than 150 max.concurrent.connection.